# Securely passing user input to command

Tags: ssh, command-line, security

I have a daemon `daemon` running in Server A.

There, there's an argument based script to control the daemon `daemon_adm.py` (Server A). Through this script I can insert "messages" to `daemon` coming from user input. Free text, whatever you like it to be.

Then, there's a web interface in Server B for `daemon_adm.py` in PHP using the phpseclib's SSH2 class.

I know that is strongly discouraged to pass user input to the command line, but well, there's must be a way to pass the text from the web Server B to `daemon_adm.py` in Server A.

How can I securely pass a text as argument to a command line utility?

Even if I echo the arguments and pipe them to `daemon_adm.py` like this:

```php
<?php 
$command = '/path/to/daemon_adm.py "'.$text.'"';
ssh->exec($command);
// or whatever other library or programming language
?>
```

since this command is executed by a ssh interface with a formatted string, code could be injected

```php
<?php 
$text = 'safetext"; echo "hazard"';
$command = '/path/to/daemon_adm.py "'.$text.'"';
ssh->exec($command);
// command sent: /path/to/daemon_adm.py "safetext"; echo "hazard"
?>
```

My current option in mind is encoding every user input to base64 (which as far as I know doesn't use quotes and spaces in its character set) and decode it inside `daemon_adm.py` like this:

```php
<?php 
$text = 'safetext"; echo "hazard"';

// Enconding it to base64

$command = '/path/to/daemon_adm.py '.$encoded_text;
ssh->exec($command);

// command sent: /path/to/daemon_adm.py c2FmZXRleHQiOyBlY2hvICJoYXphcmQi
?>
```

Is this safe enough or convoluted?

-- EDIT --

One indirect solution as indicated by Barmar would be to made `daemon_adm.py` accept the text data from stdin, and not as a shell parsable argument.

Comment: Why not use `"$*"`? It's just your flattened shell arg array delimited with double quotes - it can be passed as a single argument to another process. You might avoid `ssh` doing anything with it if you put in a heredoc on `<&[3-9]` - the shell will expand it to fill the heredoc and pass it off as a file descriptor - but its contents arent interpreted. Your target process can then read it in at leisure. You might do the same w/ `env` as well, but that requires more care. Anyway, it can also be passed as a single arg of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert a string in a shell snippet and arrange for the shell to interpret the string literally, there are two relatively simple approaches:

- Surround the string with single quotes, and replace each single quote `'` by the 4-character string `'\''`.
- Prefix each ASCII punctuation character with `\` (you may prefix other characters as well), and replace newlines with `'␤'` or `"␤"` (newline between single or double quotes).

When invoking a remote command over SSH, keep in mind that the remote shell will expand the command, and in addition, if you're invoking SSH via a local shell, the local shell will also perform expansion, so you need to quote twice.

PHP provides the [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) function to escape shell special characters. Snce [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) performs expansion, call it twice on the string you want to protect.

Note that this is fine for text strings, but not for byte strings. Most shells won't let null bytes through.

Another approach which is less error-prone and allows arbitrary byte strings through, but requires changing what runs at the other end, is to [pass the string on the remote command's standard input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160107).

Comment: He's using phpseclib - not a local shell - to perform the commands - so he only needs one round of expansion.

Answer (score 2):

`ssh2::exec()` returns a stream, which is connected to the `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` of the remote command. So you can do:

```
$command = '/path/to/daemon_adm.py';
$stream = $ssh->exec($command);
fwrite($stream, "$text\n");
```

If you don't want to pass the parameters via stdin, you can use [`escapeshellarg()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php):

```
$command = '/path/to/daemon_adm.py ' . escapeshellarg($text);
$ssh->exec($command);
```

Comment: That would be with php's ssh2 library and `ssh2_shell()`.
Still using your example, let `$command="/bin/ls "` and `$text="-l; echo 'hazard';"` then reading `$stream` will show me the `ls -l` ouput and the word "hazard". `$text` contents should never be executed by the shell.

Comment: In my answer `$text` is sent to the command's standard input, it's not a command line argument.

Comment: Since `/bin/ls` doesn't do anything with its standard input, it will ignore `$text`.

Comment: Then `daemon_adm.py` should not accept any user input as an argument and instead use stdin to accept any user data? That's the preferred method to accept user input?

Comment: That's how you have to do it if you want to hide the input. And it looks like what you're doing in the question, since you use `echo ... | daemon_adm.py`.

Comment: Though I think it would be better to know if there's a safe way to pass as argument an user input to a command.

Comment: Oh that example, yes, is inferring that I'm getting the data from stdin. My mistake, I read it in some other question. Let me edit

Comment: Command line arguments are visible to anyone using `ps`, so it's not a good way to pass input that you want to be private.

Comment: If you're just trying to escape the shell metacharacters, use `escapeshellargs()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like...

```php
$ssh->enablePTY();
$ssh->exec('/path/to/daemon_adm.py');
$ssh->write('...');
echo $ssh->read();
```